# How to find pod termination reason from within pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

Here I am using Kubernetes 1.15.3. Is there any way to find termination reason from within pod. while the pod terminates Kubernetes sends the SIGTERM signal to the container's main process when pod's memory exceeds. on pod describe I can see exit status code 137 but is there any way to it from the inside pod.

Answer (score 1):

When you exceed your memory limit, you do not receive and SIGTERM. It’s a SIGKILL and it is not a catchable signal. Your process just ceases to exist.

Comment: That is not how memory limits work, they are not a Kubernetes feature per se. K8s sets the limit in the container runtime, the thing while actually enforces it is the kernel's OOMKiller subsystem. As for a graceful version, yes check out https://github.com/16Bitt/kubemem

Comment: (though as a warning, exec probes themselves have had issues over the years)